# java displaymode exception

Tags: java, swing, exception, awt

I am writing a very simple full screen GUI, but I keep receiving an error. Here is the code:

```
package me.Kenny.GUI_WINDOW_INITILIZATION;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(1200,800,32,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run(dm);
    }

    public void run(DisplayMode dm1) {
        setBackground(Color.PINK);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        Screen s = new Screen();

        try {           
            s.setFullScreen(dm1, this);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch(Exception e){}  
        } finally {
            s.restoreScreen();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("This is gonna be awesome", 300, 300);
    }
}
```

That was the main program. The Screen class is here:

```
package me.Kenny.GUI_WINDOW_INITILIZATION;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Screen {

    private GraphicsDevice vc;
    public Screen() {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();      
    }

    public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window) {
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(window); 

        if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {                   
            try {       
                vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
                System.out.println("is in try");
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {          
                System.out.println("Unable to set Display mode");           
            }           
        }   
    }

    public Window getFullScreenWindow() {
        return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    }

    public void restoreScreen() {       
        Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();        
        if (w != null) {
            w.dispose();
        }   
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(null); //closes window
    }
}
```

In the try/catch statement of setFullScreen, I keep getting an IllegalArgument exception whenever I try to set vc to the parameters of dm. I checked both if statement conditions to ensure they were true, and my initilization of dm appears to have the proper parameters. Every time I try running the 
program hoever, I activate the catch statement, which prints "unable to set Display Mode" on the console. Is there something I am missing in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the **actual** error message(s). Please indicate which line(s) are involved.

Comment: That `Thread.sleep(...)` shouldn't be there as you don't want to call that within a Swing program, not within a portion of code that is likely to be called on the event thread. Instead, use a Swing Timer.

Comment: Your video card may not be able to support 1200x800 (which sounds like a weird resolution to me anyway) - Take a look at [this question](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=28961.0) for some ideas about listing the supported resolutions...

Comment: Sorry about that guys

The error message reads:


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid display mode
 at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.setDisplayMode(Unknown Source)
 at me.Kenny.GUI_WINDOW_INITILIZATION.Screen.setFullScreen(Screen.java:38)
 at me.Kenny.GUI_WINDOW_INITILIZATION.Main.run(Main.java:26)
 at me.Kenny.GUI_WINDOW_INITILIZATION.Main.main(Main.java:12)